# PingTester with JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm trying to create a ping tester using java and have a fancy GUI with JavaFx.
However, I have a problem updating the TextFlow.

This is my Controller class:

```
package ahmetagic.view;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button startB;

    @FXML
    private Button stopB;

    @FXML
    private static TextFlow tf;

    private Runtime r;
    private Process p;
    private BufferedReader b;
    private boolean running;
    private Thread fred;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        tf = new TextFlow();
    }

    @FXML
    private void initTest() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    p = r.exec("ping 8.8.8.8 -t");
                    b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                        tf.getChildren().add(new Text(line);
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The TextFlow doesn't update and I think the problem is the following: Due to the fact that the Thread never escapes the loop it can't update the TextFlow, but I don't really know how I should change it

Comment: Your assessment is more or less correct. You need to run your loop in a background thread, not on the FX Application Thread. Schedule the UI updates on the FX Application Thread. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/2230/threading/7291/updating-the-ui-using-platform-runlater#t=201607312134072375967

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!